# Estimation of part of parameters from an ODE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose, we have an ODE 
$$ \frac{dy}{dt}= f(t,y;p',a)$$
or alternatively 
$$ \frac{dy}{dt}= f(t,y;p)$$
where the set of all parameters $p = (p',a)$. We only need to estimate part of parameter set $p'$  from a collection of $\sum_{i=1}^{M} {a}_{i}$ data points:
$$({t}_{1},{y}_{1,1}),({t}_{2},{y}_{1,2}),...,({t}_{{N}_{1}},{y}_{1,{N}_{1}}) $$
$$({t}_{1},{y}_{2,1}),({t}_{2},{y}_{2,2}),...,({t}_{{N}_{2}},{y}_{2,{N}_{2}})$$
$$...$$
$$({t}_{1},{y}_{M,1}),({t}_{2},{y}_{M,2}),...,({t}_{{N}_{M}},{y}_{2,{N}_{M}})$$

where $\left\{ ({t}_{j},{y}_{i,j})\right\},j=1,...,N_j$ denotes data points for $i$-th value of $a$. 
One could now determine optimal values for the parameter $p'$ by minimizing error
$$E(p')=\sum_{i=1}^{M}\sum_{j=1}^{{N}_{i}}\left| y({t}_{j};p',{a}_{i}) -{y}_{i,j}\right|^2$$

The problem is if M is very large say M = 20, it is very cumbersome to write 20 slightly different function for each a.  I am just wondering  what tips are needed to call 
the solver fminsearch in Matlab in case of partly estimated parameters problems.